# Private browsing history in firefox

Tags: 14.04, firefox

How to find the history of browsing done with private browsing window in Firefox version 47.0 in Ubuntu 14.04. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's the point of private browsing that there are as little records of it as possible. In private browsing mode, Firefox doesn't record

- the visited pages, i. e. the history
- entries into forms (including passwords) or the search bar
- downloads
- cookies
- cached web content, offline web content and user data

So, you can't find the history of a private browsing session because it doesn't exist, and it doesn't exist on purpose ;)

Comment: how should a system administrator find this.

Comment: You **can't** find it, because it does not exist. It's the purpose of the private browsing mode that those things are **not recorded**. And you can't find or read what has never been written.